# How to pass props via Route in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I have my Parent App.js file where I have two child components, Products, and Cart. I am trying to pass my `cart` property to child Cart.js but haven't been successful.

App.js

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import {
  Route,
  BrowserRouter as Router,
} from 'react-router-dom';

import Cart from './components/Cart';
import Product from './components/Product';

function App() {
  const [cart, setCart]= useState([]);
  const addToCart=(product)=>{
    console.log("addToCart button clicked",product)
    setCart([...cart, {...product}])
}

  return (
 
    <Router>
       
      <Route path="/home/" 
      render ={()=> < Product addToCart={addToCart}/>}
       />
      <Route path="/cart/" 
      render ={()=> < Cart cart={cart} />} 
       />
    <div className="App">
    </div>
    </Router>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Cart.js

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Cart({cart}) {
    return (
        <div >
           hello
            <div className="products" >
            {cart.map((product,  idx)=>(
            <div key={idx}>
                <h3>{product.name}</h3>
                <h4>{product.cost}</h4>
                <img src={product.image} alt = {product.name} />
       
        </div>
      ))}
      </div>
      <div>

      </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Product.js

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';


export default function Product({addToCart}) {

    const [products]=useState([
        {
            name: 'iPhone',
            cost : '$899.99',
            image: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQB6BMWrPXA9KyTtxa6o600mjeUNJ7zSXgaNt--FDCR6YjQ4XWS5G1J3dSF5ChurfQEGxorkxYs&usqp=CAc',
          },
          {
            name: 'Samsung',
            cost : '$599.99',
            image: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQUGMCcF3_XBIKH5Dja-9iCkRP4CSA-CYaylQ&usqp=CAU'
          }
    ])



    return(
        <div className="main-page">
        <h1>Product Page </h1>
        <div className="products" >
         {products.map((product,  idx)=>(
           <div key={idx}>
             <h3>{product.name}</h3>
             <h4>{product.cost}</h4>
             <img src={product.image} alt = {product.name} />
             <button onClick={()=>addToCart(product)}
             >Add to Cart</button>
           </div>
         ))}
         </div>
         <div>
   
         </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

`localhost:3000/` shows all the products but when I go to `localhost:3000/cart/` I don't see my cart items. The mistake I am making I think is in the Route.

```
<Route path="/cart/" 
      render ={()=> < Cart cart={cart} />} 
  />
```

How should I pass the cart variable from App.js to Cart.js ?

Comment: Well, since ‘cart’ is pretty complex, you probably don’t want to pass it via the router. Since you’ll probably need to access in many different places on your app, I would suggest turning the cart state into a [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#api).

Comment: Ignore the first sentence of my comment, I misread the code a bit. Everything after that stands.

Comment: but why in the current case its not displaying the cart? Without a Router, the program works just fine. This program breaks when I add a Router and try to pass the cart via Route.

Comment: What happens when you don't use the `render` prop on the route, and instead use the [recommended method](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start/1st-example-basic-routing): `<Route path="/cart"><Cart cart={cart} /></Route>`, and also use a `<Switch />`

Comment: I did that too, it's still now showing the cart items.